# Is there a way to return more than just text with PHP/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm trying to change the style of '$.notify' within my AJAX code from my PHP form processing code. I need it to return 'success' or 'error'.

Here's an example of my AJAX code:

```
    $(function() {
        $("#name-submit").submit(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($("#name").val() != "") {
                $.ajax({
                    method: "POST",
                    url: "<?=updateNameFile?>",
                    data: {
                        name: $("#name").val()
                    }
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    $.notify(msg, "success");
                });
            } else {
                $.notify("<?php echo $language_form_message_invalid_data; ?>", "error");
            }
        });
    });
```

Here's an example of my PHP code:

```
    public function updateName($name, $id){
        $pdo = $this->pdo;

        if(isset($name) && isset($i)){
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare('UPDATE users SET name = ? WHERE id = ?');

            if($stmt->execute([$name, $id])){
                $_SESSION['user']['name'] = $name;
                session_regenerate_id();
                return true;
            } else {
                $this->msg = 'An error occurred when changing your name';
                return false;
            }
        } else {
            $this->msg = 'Please provide valid information';
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Again, I need it to return 'error' or 'success' into my AJAX code to style the notifications correctly.

Comment: Could return json and have one property be status and the other be the message

Comment: Which JQ version? (3 recommended) *"Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are removed as of jQuery 3.0. You can use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead."* [JQ doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone OP isn't using any of those and is already using `done()`

Comment: @charlietfl ...but not `fail`

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone fine but what does that have to do with the deprecation notice? Just seems confusing for no reason. I believe you have misinterpreted what OP is asking

Comment: It shows the async implementation of current and former JQ versions.

Comment: @Quasimodo'sclone that is completely irrelevant to the question. OP is asking something completely different

Comment: Not totally clear what is meant by 'error' or 'success', however, if PHP should return an error, it could be done by `header` function using one of the [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes). Again JQ `fail` is needed then.

Comment: What do you mean  by _"return more than just text"_? What is `$.notify()`? `deferred.notify()`?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Notify JS is a jQuery plugin that returns a small popup with feedback. $.notify("This would return a red popup", "error"); I need to be able to return with 'error' or 'success'.